# How do I npm install on mac without errors?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I can't get past the errors; "node -v" and "npm -v" give valid responses but "npm install" gives me the following error:

````
➜  React git:(main) ✗ npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Applications/GitHub/React/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Applications/GitHub/React/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/andreeamanole/.npm/_logs/2023-08-25T11_00_13_464Z-debug-0.log```


Tried deleting cache since some people recommended that, still didn't work...
````

Comment: `npm init` Will fix your all issues. The error you're encountering indicates that you're trying to run `npm install` within a directory where npm cannot find a `package.json` file. The `package.json` file is crucial as it lists the dependencies and metadata for your project. Without it, npm doesn't know what packages to install.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs of [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install/) command, you have to have a *package.json* file if you want to run the command as-is, as it'll install all the dependencies from that file. The error clearly says that it cannot file that file in the current path. In order to generate that file, you need to run [`npm init`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init/) command and follow the on-screen instructions.